# Is there a better strategy for beating Agatha at the lowest possible level in Pokémon Red/Blue?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

Inspired by my [beating Lorelei with a low-level Pokémon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365754/lowest-possible-lvl-to-beat-lorelei-from-pok%C3%A9mon-red-blue) I also did [beat Agatha with a lvl 5 Starmie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nAfSI_SJ3E).

My strategy is:

1. get one Doubleteam up at Gengar (which takes some tries because it
   has Nightshade/Confuseray and is faster)
2. get Substitute up
3. spam Doubleteam to get +6 evasion
4. somehow be lucky that Agatha doesn't switch to Golbat and uses Haze,
   which removes all stat-changes
5. spam all x-items (preferably on Agatha's first Gengar) for reapplying
   the badge-bonus.
6. (using a Dire Hit to avoid critical hits would be also a good idea!)
7. use Psychic

Now in retrospect I should have brought elixirs with me, but it worked out anyway.

But is there a better way, maybe forcing Golbat to switch(and not be hazed) with some trick?

Right now it's a luck-based strategy and I would like to know if there are any tricks, such that the luck part is reduced to a minimum.

Off the top of my hat I see only RNG-manip and I don't know if it's possible that Agatha always uses moves that don't harm me (no Haze would be great!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar strategy to your [Lorelei strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365754/lowest-possible-pokemon-level-to-beat-lorelei-in-pok%C3%A9mon-red-blue) should work. However, because Agatha has both Pokemon immune to Horn Drill or Guillotine and Pokemon immune to Fissure, you need a Pokemon who has access to both. Fortunately Nidoking has both, available at level 16.

Use Double Team ASAP to reduce the chance of being hit by Hypnosis. Whenever you get hit by Confuse Ray or Night Shade, use a Full Restore (or Full Heal if just Confuse Ray). If you get put to sleep, immediately use the Poke Flute or a Full Restore if damaged in order to avoid Dream Eater. Continue until you are at max evasion. The only way Gengar can KO you in one turn is if you take both Night Shade and confusion damage without healing, which is why we heal as soon as either happens. After using Double Team six times, then use 6 X Speeds + X Accuracy to outspeed and OHKO her entire team.

[Unlike Lorelei](http://wiki.pokemonspeedruns.com/index.php/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red/Blue/Yellow_Trainer_AI), being weak to one of Gengar's types does not guarantee it'll use it. So you should have at least 57 HP to survive the first Gengar's Night Shade. Agatha has a small chance to switch each turn which is RNG based and unavoidable. Switching to Haunter does not change the strategy as well as the second Gengar if you have at least 61 max HP (though if you KO a Pokemon beforehand, you may gain that experience from level up). Switching to Golbat, however, can be troublesome because of Haze to remove your boosts. It is for this reason that I do not recommend using Substitute since it is both not needed and the turn taken to use it increases the chance of her switching.

Of note, you could use the same Nidoran that you used for Lorelei in the same Elite Four Battle, provided that you let it evolve into Nidorino after Lorelei, bring a Moon Stone to evolve it into Nidoking, and bring the TM Fissure to teach it after becoming Nidoking.

Comment: hi, unfortunately Agatha's AI is such, that she doesn't always use super-effective moves, otherwise I would have gone for an Exeggutor (weak to poison and flying). source: http://wiki.pokemonspeedruns.com/index.php/Pok%C3%A9mon_Red/Blue/Yellow_Trainer_AI

Comment: It could still work if the Nidoking has at least 57 HP. This enables it to survive the first Gengar's Night Shade. Whenver Nidoking gets confused or hit by Night Shade, use a Full Restore (or Full Heal if confused at full health). Random switches are RNG, but the strategy remains the same if a switch happens to Haunter and (if HP >60) the 2nd Gengar.

Comment: true that, I might make a video today of beating the whole elite 4 with just one Nidoran M which gets evolved^^. Nidoking has at lvl 25 (which it should have after Lorelei+Bruno) 75 HP. and after 6 x-speeds it has at least 42*4=168 speed which outspeeds every Pokémon she has.

Comment: I've updated the comments accordingly

Comment: funnily I set up on Golbat and beat her on my first try! Haze btw also removes the effect of x-accuracy, so bring some redundant with you. See here: https://youtu.be/wRaNod5EVPg